# A Persistent Store for Increment/Decrementing Integers Easily and Quickly

Tags: performance, atomic, persistent

Does there exist some sort of persistent key-value like store that allows for quick and easy incrementing, decrementing, and retrieval of integers (and nothing else). I know that I could implement something with a SQL database, but I see two drawbacks to that:

1. It's heavyweight for the task at hand. All I need is the ability to say "server[key].inc()" or "server[key].dec()"
2. I need the ability to handle potentially thousands of writes to a single key simultaneously. I don't want to deal with excessive resource contention. Change the value and get out - that's all I need.

I know memcached supports inc/dec, but it's not persistent. My strategy at this point is going to be to use a SQL server behind a queueing system of some sort such that there's only one process updating the database. It just seems... harder than it should be.

Is there something someone can recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Redis](http://redis.io) is a key-value store that supports several data types. Integer is present, along with incr and decr commands.

Comment: Still a bit more than what I want, but I'll take it. Thanks.